# Unable to load FBFriendPickerViewController using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am making an replica of Scrumptous sample app (ios facebook sdk version - 3.10 ) using Storyboard approach

I am able to load user name and profile image correctly.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Do nothing for now
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 2:
        if (!self.friendPickerController) {

            self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc]
                                           initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];



            // Set the friend picker delegate
            self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;

            self.friendPickerController.title = @"Select friends";
        }

        [self.friendPickerController loadData];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.friendPickerController
                                             animated:true];
        break;
}

}
```

With below approach we can instantiateViewController but we need a valid identifier

```
         /*

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

*/
```